# Angular won't display variable

Tags: angular

How can i display the two variables in the frontend? They don't show up.

https://angular.io/guide/observables

```
<p>Latitude: <span id="latitude">{{ latitude }}</span></p>
<p>Longitude: <span id="longitude">{{ longitude }}</span></p>
```

```
// Call subscribe() to start listening for updates.
const locationsSubscription = locations.subscribe({
  next(position) {
    console.log('Current Position: ', position);
    let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    let longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  },
  error(msg) {
    console.log('Error Getting Location: ', msg);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast fix: declare your variables in the component

```
export class YourComponent {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number
}

/ Call subscribe() to start listening for updates.


const locationsSubscription = locations.subscribe({
    next(position) {
    console.log('Current Position: ', position);
    this.atitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  },
  error(msg) {
    console.log('Error Getting Location: ', msg);
  }
});
```

Better fix, use the reactive way

```
export class YourComponent {
        latitude$ = this.locations.map(location=> location.latitude);
        longitude$ = this.locations.map(location=> location.longitude);
    }
```

and use it together with the async pipe in the template

Comment: Version 2 brings a white page and this error:  ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(19,20): error TS2339: Property 'locations' does not exist on type 'AppModule'.
    src/app/app.module.ts(20,21): error TS2339: Property 'locations' does not exist on type 'AppModule'.
    src/app/app.module.ts(51,29): error TS2339: Property 'coords' does not exist on type '{}'.
    src/app/app.module.ts(52,30): error TS2339: Property 'coords' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: Version 1 brings that error: ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(51,29): error TS2339: Property 'coords' does not exist on type '{}'.
    src/app/app.module.ts(52,30): error TS2339: Property 'coords' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: export class AppModule {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}

Answer (score 0):

share more code so we'd get more context, but from the look of this you need to make your variables class properties meaning

```
    class A {
      latitude: string;
      longitude: string;

      const locationsSubscription = locations.subscribe({
  next(position) {
    console.log('Current Position: ', position);
    this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  },
  error(msg) {
    console.log('Error Getting Location: ', msg);
  }
});
    }
```

mind this.latitude // this.longitude

Comment: If i put the whole code in the export class AppModule Block there is the following error: i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
    
    ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(47,31): error TS2663: Cannot find name 'locations'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.locations'?
    src/app/app.module.ts(59,12): error TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
    src/app/app.module.ts(60,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'locationsSubscription'.

Comment: you need to share more of your code so we can properly help you